# Start listening to user selections on Eclipse start-up

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse plugin for performing equivalence check on two programs. Once the users selected two programs in the project explorer, the "initially grayed-out" icon is enabled, and the user may click on it to perform equivalence check.

The thing is, when I install the plugin in Eclipse, it does not listen to user selections. Somehow, I have to "activate" my selections class when Eclipse starts-up. For this purpose, I am using a class that implements **IStartup**.

Here is my selections class, if that is needed;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class SelectionView extends ViewPart{

static ArrayList<String> paths=new ArrayList<>(2);

private ISelectionListener listener = new ISelectionListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection) {
        if (sourcepart != SelectionView.this) {
            showSelection(sourcepart, selection);
        }
    }
};

public void showSelection(IWorkbenchPart sourcepart, ISelection selection) {
    if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {        
        IStructuredSelection ss = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
        Object[] ob=ss.toArray();
        String path=getPath().substring(0,getPath().lastIndexOf('/'));
        String file=null;
        for(int i=0;i<ob.length;i++){
            if((file=ob[i].toString()).endsWith(".c")){
                paths.add(0,path+"/"+file);
                if(paths.size()>=2){
                    Handler.return_val=true;
                    Handler.arg1=paths.get(0);
                    Handler.arg2=paths.get(1);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
public String getPath(){
    IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart(); 
    IFile file = (IFile) workbenchPart.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
    String path=ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString()+file.getFullPath();
    return path;
    }   
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {   
    getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(listener);
    }

public void dispose() {
    getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().removeSelectionListener(listener);
    super.dispose();
    }
@Override
public void setFocus() {}

}
```

Could someone please help me with how I "activate" this class on Eclipse start-up? That is, what code to write in the **earlyStartup()** method of the IStartup interface to start listening to user selections as soon as Eclipse starts-up?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you show here is all part of a view, you can't set up a listener that is part of a view in earlyStartup. You would have to refactor this code, or maybe just check the selections when the view opens.

Comment: @greg-449, is there any other way to listen to selections without opening the view? Excuse my naivety, but I am very new to Eclipse plugin development. But I do understand what you have written, that until the view opens, I can't listen to selections. Can you suggest me how to modify this code to listen to selections in early startup?

Comment: @greg-449 I figured-out a way to do this using one of your many other answers on the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have your own activator, you can hook workspace selection services on activator start method.

Comment: And you could find code for best practice which from eclipse built-in compare with each other context menu activation.